# how to refresh tab content when click on the tab?

Tags: jsp, tabs, refresh

```
<div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMenu(event, 'Pending')">Pending</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMenu(event, 'Completed')">Completed</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMenu(event, 'Rejected')">Rejected</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openMenu(event, 'All')" id="defaultOpen">All</button>
</div>

<div id="Pending" class="tabcontent">
<%
 perform db selection pending records
%>

<div id="All" class="tabcontent">
<%
 perform db selection all records
%>

<script>
function openMenu(evt, Status) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        
    }
    document.getElementById(Status).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

refer to https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp example. i develop a tab to show different status content.
I would perform records status change but i don't know how to refresh the tab content when some record status is changed.

Comment: The link doesn't go to example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do faster and simplier using jQuery:

> ```
> <html>
> <body>
> <head>
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
> </head>
> <div class="tab">
>     <button class="tablinks" data-val="Pending">Pending</button>
>     <button class="tablinks" data-val="Completed">Completed</button>
>     <button class="tablinks" data-val="Rejected">Rejected</button>
>     <button class="tablinks active" data-val="All">All</button>
> </div>
>
> <div id="Pending" class="tabcontent">
> <%
>  perform db selection pending records
> %>
>
> <div id="All" class="tabcontent">
> <%
>  perform db selection all records
> %>
>
> <script>
> $(".tablinks").click(function(){
>   var val = $(this).attr("data-val");
>   if(val=="All") $('.tabcontent').show();
>   else {
>       $('.tabcontent').hide();
>       $('#'+val).show();
>       $(".tablinks").removeClass("active");
>       $(this).addClass("active");
>   }
> });
> </script>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```